# Convert a 2D array into a 1D array error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have made a program, but I have a problem and I don't know where but it think its int the convertion. I want to convert from 2d to 1d.
So I have this code:

```
            System.out.print("\nEnter the employee's (1) Basic Pay (2) Housing Allowance (3) Travel Allowance (example: 4000 500 300): ");
        salary_detail[0][employee_counter] = sc.nextDouble();
        salary_detail[1][employee_counter] = sc.nextDouble();
        salary_detail[2][employee_counter] = sc.nextDouble();
        net_salary[employee_counter]= salary_detail[1][employee_counter]+salary_detail[2][employee_counter]+salary_detail[3][employee_counter];
```

employee_counter is 0
So first of all I scan the number.
But when I want to collect all of this numbers to another array 1d it won't work and I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at project1.Project1.addRecord(Project1.java:90)
at project1.Project1.main(Project1.java:48)
```

Java Result: 1

all this is inside a method 
so how can i fix that ?

Comment: can you provide complete code so that we can look into it what are you doing. What's sc, whats the input , from where you are getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`net_salary[employee_counter]= salary_detail[0][employee_counter]+salary_detail[1][employee_counter]+salary_detail[2][employee_counter];`

The first index of an array is 0, so the last will be 2 instead of 3. Since your array has only a length of 3 and you are trying to access the item at index 3 (this is actually the fourth item) you are getting an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @AnmarMashat No problem! Hope you understand now what you did wrong... If it helped you, you may accept the answer.